# instagram-api gem in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4, instagram

I'm trying to get a small rails app built that allows a user to authenticate with Instagram, then access their own feed. I'm struggling!

I've used the omniauth-instagram gem to get basic authentication (when I log in, I can access my name and UID).

However, any attempt to access my feed has led to errors that mention an access token being required.

I've just stumbled across the 'instagram-api' gem which I'm about to have a go with. But being a ruby n00b I'm not sure how to implement the [example (Sinatra) code](https://github.com/caseyscarborough/instagram) in my controller:

```
# Instantiate a new client.
client = Instagram.client(
  :client_id     => '2bfe9d72a4aae8f06a31025b7536be80',
  :client_secret => '9d667c2b7fae7a329f32b6df17926154',
  :callback_url  => 'http://example.com/'
)

# Visit the authorization URL in your browser and login.
client.authorize_url
# => "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=2bfe9d72a4aae8f06a31025b7536be80&redirect_uri=http://example.com/&response_type=code"

# Retrieve the code from the URL parameters and use it to get an access token.
client.get_access_token('88fb89ab65454da2a06f2c6dacd09436')
# => '1313345.3fedf64.a0fcb7f40e02fe3da50500'
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [instagram-ruby-gem](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem) which I've used and is well supported.

Comment: this gem is no longer being maintained

Answer (score 0):

You could follow these [manual instructions](https://coderwall.com/p/cfgneq) to retrieve the access token, then store it as an environment variable for reference within your app.

Not sure how to automate all this within a controller though.